# I want to write a 75000x10000 matrix with float values effectively into a database

Tags: python, sql, django, pandas, bigdata

thanks for hearing me out.

I have a dataset that is a matrix of shape `75000x10000` filled with float values. Think of it like heatmap/correlation matrix. I want to store this in a SQLite database (SQLite because I am modifying an existing **Django project**). The source data file is 8 GB in size and I am trying to use python to carry out my task.

I have ***tried to use pandas chunking*** to read the file into python and transform it into unstacked pairwise indexed data and write it out onto a json file. But this method is eating up my computational cost. For a chunk of size `100x10000` it generates a 200 MB json file.

This json file will be used as a fixture to form the SQLite database in Django backend.

Is there a better way to do this? Faster/Smarter way. ***I don't think a 90 GB odd json file written out taking a full day is the way to go. Not even sure if Django databases can take this load.***

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may want to explore hdf5 or possibly parquet using spark.  https://medium.com/@ph_singer/handling-huge-matrices-in-python-dff4e31d4417

Comment: 75,000 X 10,000 is *a lot* of data to be pushing. Expect whatever solution you use with `pandas` to have some waiting time. Can you do any summarization on the file? grouping categories, aggregating values? Also - what does your data consist of. is it a lot of zeroes where we can use something like a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)?

Comment: The dataset is not sparse. And my aim is not to summarize the data. I want to eventually move the matrix from source file to a Django SQLite database. The middleman job is the huge obstacle here.

Comment: How are you planning on having this matrix in the sqlite database? What kind of table layout?

Comment: I want to insert my big matrix dataset into a sqlite django DB.

The matrix can be unstacked as [index | column | value]  

The DB requires a format of {'model':'xxx','pk': int, 'fields': {'feat1':index , 'feat2':column, 'value':value}}  

Creating the latter is what is creating the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is quite impressive for what it is, but it's probably not going to give you the performance you are looking for at that scale, so even though your existing project is Django on SQLite I would recommend simply writing a Python wrapper for a different data backend and just using that from within Django.

More importantly, forget about using Django models for something like this; they are an abstraction layer built for convenience (mapping database records to Python objects), not for performance. Django would very quickly choke trying to build 100s of millions of objects since it doesn't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Instead, you'll want to use a database type / engine that's suited to the type of queries you want to make; if a typical query consists of a hundred point queries to get the data in particular 'cells', a key-value store might be ideal; if you're typically pulling ranges of values in individual 'rows' or 'columns' then that's something to optimize for; if your queries typically involve taking sub-matrices and performing predictable operations on them then you might improve the performance significantly by precalculating certain cumulative values; and if you want to use the full dataset to train machine learning models, you're probably better off not using a database for your primary storage at all (since databases by nature sacrifice fast-retrieval-of-full-raw-data for fast-calculations-on-interesting-subsets), especially if your ML models can be parallelised using something like Spark.

No DB will handle everything well, so it would be useful if you could elaborate on the workload you'll be running on top of that data -- the kind of questions you want to ask of it?